# Redirect from a .asp page / Access database

Tags: asp-classic, redirect

I need this page:

http://address.com/research/staff/profile.asp?id=p0026510

to redirect to basic HTML page.

Is there anyway I can do this?  I have seen on here some answers about making a 301 redirect but I am not sure how to set one of these files up.

I have tried typing:

```
Redirect 301 /research/staff/profile.asp?id=p0026510 /about/staff/p0026510/p0026510.asp
```

Into the .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `response.redirect "http://address.com/destination_page.html"`

Comment: Classic asp doesn't use a .htaccess file, it uses a global.asa. So you would redirect like the comment above suggests. But if you are using a .htaccess file, it sounds like you are on a Linux box. In which case, the method above wont work, because the .asp file will never run.